# Python: Generalized input transformation decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

Writing a decorator to transform inputs of a function: Basic.

Writing a function that makes an input-transforming decorator for any single-input-transformer: Easy

Here is one way:

```py
def input_wrap_decorator(preprocess):
    def decorator(func):
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(preprocess(*args, **kwargs))
        return func_wrapper
    return decorator
```

Consider the following function:

```py
def red_riding_hood(adj, noun='eyes'):
    return 'What {adj} {noun} you have!'.format(adj=adj, noun=noun)
```

Example of use:

```py
assert red_riding_hood('big') == 'What big eyes you have!'
assert red_riding_hood('long', 'ears') == 'What long ears you have!'
```

Our `input_wrap_decorator` allows us to easily transform the first argument of `red_riding_hood` at will:

```py
wrapped_func = input_wrap_decorator(lambda x: x.upper())(red_riding_hood)
assert wrapped_func('big') == 'What BIG eyes you have!'

wrapped_func = input_wrap_decorator(lambda x: 'very ' + x)(red_riding_hood)
assert wrapped_func('big') == 'What very big eyes you have!'
```

But if what if we want to transform other, or all, inputs of a function? Again, writing a specific decorator is basic, but there doesn't seem to be a single natural way to write a (parametrized) wrapper for the general case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some answers to my own question. I intend to select someone else's answer to be THE answer if I find it to be more complete.

It seems there's no avoiding of imposing a protocol on the preprocess function, unless there's an obscure way to handle the args/kwargs conundrum gracefully. (Obscure only because I don't know of it.)

Here are several choices.

**preprocess returns (transformed) args tuple**

```py
def wrap_args_deco(preprocess):
    """Preprocess needs to return the tuple of args (non-keyworded arguments) 
    that should be passed on to the decorated func."""
    def decorator(func):
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # NOTE: the only difference with input_wrap_decorator is the * before the preprocess
            return func(*preprocess(*args, **kwargs))  
        return func_wrapper
    return decorator
```

Example of use:

```py
def trans_args(adj, noun):
    '''adj is capitalized and noun is quoted'''
    return adj.upper(), '"{}"'.format(noun) 
wrapped_func = wrap_args_deco(trans_args)(red_riding_hood)
assert wrapped_func('big', 'eyes') == 'What BIG "eyes" you have!'
```

There are some limitations here. For instance, you need to specify transformations for all arguments that don't have defaults, no matter if you want to transform them or not.

**preprocess returns (transformed) kwargs dict**

```py
def wrap_kwargs_deco(preprocess):
    """Preprocess needs to return the dict of kwargs (keyworded, or named arguments) 
    that should be passed on to the decorated func."""
    def decorator(func):
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # NOTE: the only difference with input_wrap_decorator is the ** before the preprocess
            return func(**preprocess(*args, **kwargs))  
        return func_wrapper
    return decorator
```

Example:

```py
def trans_kwargs(adj, noun):
    '''adj is capitalized and noun is quoted'''
    return {'adj': adj.upper(), 'noun': '"{}"'.format(noun)}
wrapped_func = wrap_kwargs_deco(trans_kwargs)(red_riding_hood)
assert wrapped_func('big', 'eyes') == 'What BIG "eyes" you have!'
```

**preprocess returns a (transformed) (args, kwargs) tuple**

You could get (sorta) the best of both worlds by having the preprocess function return a transformed args (tuple) and kwargs (dict).

```py
def wrap_args_and_kwargs_deco(preprocess):
    """Preprocess needs to return a the tuple (arg, kwargs) where 
    arg is the list/tuple of (transformed) non-keyworded arguments and
    kwargs is the dict of (transformed) keyworded (a.k.a. "named") arguments
    that should be passed on to the decorated func."""
    def decorator(func):
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            args, kwargs = preprocess(*args, **kwargs)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return func_wrapper
    return decorator
```

Example:

```py
def trans_kwargs(adj, noun):
    return (adj.upper(),), {'noun': '"{}"'.format(noun)}
wrapped_func = wrap_args_and_kwargs_deco(trans_kwargs)(red_riding_hood)
assert wrapped_func('big', 'eyes') == 'What BIG "eyes" you have!'
```

**specifying transformers for individual (keyworded) arguments**

The options proposed above are more general than the following in the sense that they can base their transformation logic on a global view of all argument values. But in most cases you'll probably only need to transform an argument based on its name only. In that case, here's a solution to that problem offering a nicer interface.

```py
from functools import wraps

def transform_args(**trans_func_for_arg):
    """
    Make a decorator that transforms function arguments before calling the function.
    Works with plain functions and bounded methods.
    """
    def transform_args_decorator(func):
        if len(trans_func_for_arg) == 0:  # if no transformations were specified...
            return func  # just return the function itself
        else:
            @wraps(func)
            def transform_args_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                # get a {argname: argval, ...} dict from *args and **kwargs
                # Note: Didn't really need an if/else here but I am assuming that...
                # Note: ... getcallargs gives us an overhead that can be avoided if there's only keyword args.
                if len(args) > 0:
                    val_of_argname = inspect.signature(func).bind_partial(*args, **kwargs).arguments
                else:
                    val_of_argname = kwargs
                for argname, trans_func in trans_func_for_arg.items():
                    val_of_argname[argname] = trans_func(val_of_argname[argname])
                # apply transform functions to argument values
                return func(**val_of_argname)

            return transform_args_wrapper

    return transform_args_decorator
```

Here is an example with more functionality coverage than the others:

```py
# Example with a plain function
def f(a, b, c='default c'):
    return "a={a}, b={b}, c={c}".format(a=a, b=b, c=c)
def prepend_root(x):
    return 'ROOT/' + x

def test(f):
    assert f('foo', 'bar', 3) == 'a=foo, b=bar, c=3'
    ff = transform_args()(f)  # no transformation specification, so function is unchanged
    assert ff('foo', 'bar', 3) == 'a=foo, b=bar, c=3'
    ff = transform_args(a=prepend_root)(f)  # prepend root to a
    assert ff('foo', 'bar', 3) == 'a=ROOT/foo, b=bar, c=3'
    ff = transform_args(b=prepend_root)(f)  # prepend root to b
    assert ff('foo', 'bar', 3) == 'a=foo, b=ROOT/bar, c=3'
    ff = transform_args(a=prepend_root, b=prepend_root)(f)  # prepend root to a and b
    assert ff('foo', 'bar', 3) == 'a=ROOT/foo, b=ROOT/bar, c=3'

test(f)

# Example with a bounded method
class A:
    def __init__(self, sep=''):
        self.sep = sep
    def f(self, a, b, c):
        return f"a={a}{self.sep} b={b}{self.sep} c={c}"

a = A(sep=',')
test(a.f)

# Example of decorating the method on the class itself
A.f = transform_args(a=prepend_root, b=prepend_root)(A.f)
a = A(sep=',')
assert a.f('foo', 'bar', 3) == 'a=ROOT/foo, b=ROOT/bar, c=3'
```